# Google maps api syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to simply add a google map using the api. I literally copied the code from the tutorial and pasted it to my site. I was then going to edit it after I made sure that it worked. This is in the head of my index page.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I placed the code below in a .js file. I keep getting a syntax error. Here is the code.

```
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
```

I get the error on the very last line. Can anyone tell me why when all I did was copy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote characters you copied are special characters, not the regular `'` you need to use in code.

Change it to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: for some reason the map does not show it is just a gray box, is there something else wrong with the code?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you might need to post more of your code as a separate question. Edit: looks like you did, and got your answer already

Answer (score 0):

Oh i think it's a documention bug your last line should be like that :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is error becouse of wrong apostraps neal 'load'

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Chang this with your load Event..!!